# Changing the code format for wordpress

Tags: formatting

So I have the following code:

```
global $userpro;
$output .= '<div class="mainpageauthor">';
$output .= '<a  href="'.$userpro->permalink($post->post_author).'">'.get_the_author_meta('display_name',$post->post_author).'</a>';
$output .= '</div>';
```

How would I change it to html php format? (I am not sure if I am asking it correctly).
For example, I tried to change it but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
<div class="myrelatedauthor">
   <a href="<?php $userpro->permalink($post->post_author); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);?></a>
</div>
```

Did I do it right?

Thanks

Comment: This is not really Wordpress specific, but anyway, your syntax looks OK on eye value. Just remember `global $userpro;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first, we need to get our globals. If you're in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) you can remove the `global $post` in my code, if you're outside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) `$post` may not be what you expect it to be. We'll always need the `global $userpro` though.

```
<?php 
    global $userpro,
            $post;
?>
<div class="myrelatedauthor">
    <a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink( $post->post_author ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );?>
    </a>
</div>
```

The key differences between your code and my code is that I include `global $post` and `global $userpro`. I also `echo` out the value returned from from `$userpro->permalink()`.

Comment: Ahh, i see what I did wrong. Thank you for the fix. I appreciate it! =)